# Functions about random numbers

Tags: php, arrays, random

How can I create functions that answer to:

1. How many different numbers were generated during simulation?
2. % Of appearance of the numbers from 0 to 50 ?
3. What is the number that appeared several times during the simulation?

```php
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
    $arrayRange = 1000;
    if ($numDigits <= 0) {
        return '';
    } else{
        for($i=0; $i<$arrayRange; $i++){
            echo mt_rand(0, 50) ." ";
        }
    }
}

$maxq = 100;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {
    echo $i . "<br>\n";
    randomDigits($i) . "<br>\n----<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store all the generated numbers into an array, you could use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

This will count the occurrences of multiple key values in your array (e.g. if there are 12 occurrences of the number 7) and return the result in an array. This will only work for strings and integer values.

```php
<?php
    $array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Results from the above:

```php
Array(
    [a] => 4
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 1
)
```

From there, you should be able to easily do all the methods and outputs that you wish.
Here is the basic integration with your existing code...

```php
<?php 
    $maxq = 100;
    $returned_array = [];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {    
        $returned_array = randomDigits($i); // return the generated array 
        
        // merge 'add' the two arrays, like saying i = i +2 or
        // merged_array = merged_array + array
        array_merge($returned_array, $returned_array);
        
        // here you now have one array of 1000 random values
        // print_r($returned_array);
        
        // lets do some math
        print_r(array_count_values($returned_array));
        // this will show how many values were duplicates...
        // e.g
        
        // Array ( 
        // [43] => 25  the number 43 was generated 25 times
        // [25] => 22  the number 25 was generated 22 times
        // [1] => 28   ect...
        
        // you can loop through this array here and see which value was generated several times,
        // format the results nicely, and do all sorts of maths on it as you wish
    }

    function randomDigits($numDigits) {
        $arrayRange = 1000;
        $generated_array = []; // here is an actual array that will store the generated numbers

        if ($numDigits <= 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for($i = 0; $i < $arrayRange; $i++) {
                $random = mt_rand(0, 50);
                array_push($generated_array, $random); // add the random value to the array
            }

            // here you have your array of generated numbers
            return $generated_array;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: In the case that you written you put `$array = array ( 'a', 'a', ....)` but in my case that the output generate 100 array, how can i include in one array only? could you help me writing the example with my code?

Comment: @J.arc look at edit look at edit, you were actually not generating an array of numbers, you were just generating numbers and not storing it into an array. I changed it so that you generate numbers and store it into an array. You then needed to merge that generated array into one big array that contains all values. Now with that bit array, you can get anything that you want from there.

Answer (score 1):

Example here - http://codepad.org/9Dv1CwR7

Sequence generation contains random integers for given length

```
function generate_array($count, $min, $max) {
    $arr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $arr[$i] = rand($min, $max);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Calculating percentage of given interval (with a helper  function):

```
function cnt($element, $arr){

    $cnt = array_count_values($arr);
    return $cnt[$element];
}

function percentages($min, $max, $arr) {

    $total = sizeof($arr);
    $occurences = 0;
    while ($min < $max) {
        if (!array_key_exists($min, $arr)) {
            continue;
        } else { 
            $occurences = $occurences + cnt($min, $arr); 
        }
        $min++; 
    }
    return $occurences/$total;  
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how can i fill looking the first comment of  Adrian David Smith the % of the $generated_array? Could you please help me more using the same variable name??  :)

Comment: i will try to do. let me re-explain my steps: to generate an array with given length, max and min numbers. `generate_array(10, 3, 8)` will create an array with 10 elements which are random integers between 3 and 8.  if you assign the value of this function to a variable, `$x`  it will be something like, "[3,4,5,5,4,6,5,4,7, 6]". then if you pass one of this, values to see how many times it occured in array, `cnt` will help you. e.g. `cnt(6, $x)` will return 2. if you want to calculate percentage of nums between 6,8, use `percentage(6,8, $x)`  which will return 0.3 for `$x` array.

Comment: i actually first write my code in python then convert to php. i have problems with understanding others php code :) but let me try to see what's happening on Adrian Smith's code :)

Answer (score 0):

Add all simulated values to an array, and use array_count_values to get all unique values.

```
function randomDigits($numDigits) {
        $arrayRange = 1000;
        if ($numDigits <= 0) {
            return '';
        } else{
          $arr=array();
            for($i=0; $i<$arrayRange; $i++){
                $val=mt_rand(0, 50);
                $arr[]=$val;
                echo $val ." ";
            }

            echo "\n";
            $arr=array_count_values($arr);
            echo "Total Unique numbers:".count($arr);
        }

    }
    $maxq = 100;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxq; $i++) {
        randomDigits($i) . "<br>\n----<br>\n";
    }
```